# How can I create a msg(outlook) blob in azure storage using a workflow?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps

I am creating a workflow in Azure, when an Email arrives it should create a msg(outlook file) blob, the workflow creates the blob but when I open it it shows a plain text with the content of the email, I would like to save the msg with attachments.

this is my current workflow
[image]

This is the step that creates the workflow

[image]

Comment: yeah the body will return only the body message ... you can get the attachments using the get attachment action? would it be a problem in your case ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing is the expected behavior.  Keep in mind, .msg is a format internal to Exchange/Outlook.  What you receive in the LogicApp is a LogicApp JSON representation of the same content.

Hence, there is no immediate way to get a .msg out of it.  If you just want to save the content, you can use the entire Trigger output but any future consumers would have to understand the JSON representation, not any Outlook format.